# Change bamboo plan so that I can edit it manually rather than editing it via a spec

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I have a bamboo plan that is using bamboo specs.

When I click on the Actions button to configure the plan, I cannot edit the jobs and stuff in the UI. I have to update the bamboo spec YAML file to change the plan.

How do I opt out of this behaviour? I want to be able to modify my plan in the UI as usual.

Comment: I know you're using YAML specs and this is not a direct answer to your question. But the moment I run my JavaSpecs locally from my machine, the plan configuration in the UI gets enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-19616

Comment: It's more of a _by design_ issue, I think.  But there's a feature request to provide a UI component to swap from Repo Specs based to UI based, and that feature request has a "workaround" in it.